# Интерпретатор скрипта парсера

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Необходимо разработать приложение для парсера HTML страницы.

Веб страниц много и структуры разные, что бы не писать на каждую страницу отдельный парсер, решил автоматизировать и разработать некий интерпретатор который будет обрабатывать файл (для каждой страницы свой) содержащий некий скрипт(алгоритм парсера) с командами и параметрами, например:

```
class = status !&textOut //найти класс "status" и получить значение в виде текста
div_id = page_count !&textOut //найти тег div с id "page_count" и получить значение в виде текста
li !&linkOut //найти тег li и получить значение в виде ссылок
```

Может кто-то уже и решал подобную задачу, помогите с выбором правильного паттерна для решения данной задачи

Answer (score 1):

Не занимайтесь велосипедостроительством. В общем и целом есть 2 подхода к парсингу HTML/XML - DOM и SAX

1. [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) - загружается весь документ и на гора выдается дерево документа
2. [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) - потоковая обработка документа, в разных тегах, нодах - срабатывают события, которые прогер и обрабатывает

SAX ваш случай. Туториал например [здесь](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax.html)

Comment: Эти два метода работают с XML, а мне нужно обрабатывать HTML

Comment: Для обработки html кода меня вполне устраивает Jsoup, суть проблемы заключается в том, как спроектировать проект так, что бы написать один раз программу и потом не переписывать код под каждый сайт разный парсер... для этого нужен анализатор скрипта(скрипт будет сохранен в файле, в котором записаны url, команды и параметры), что бы с помощью заданного алгоритма (в виде команд). По требованию программа будет считывать скрипт и будет знать как парсить конкретный сайт